# Delete all elasticsearch indices directly without curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I am starting elasticsearch, and getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to upgrade the mappings for the index [[documents/xOOEXQB-RzGhQp7o7NNH9w]]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataIndexUpgradeService.checkMappingsCompatibility(MetaDataIndexUpgradeService.java:172) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
```

I am not exactly sure what caused this to happen.  I did do a 
`brew upgrade elasticsearch` but I didn't note down the last version.  I am currently on elasticsearch 5.5.

I would like to just clear away all the mappings/indices for elasticsearch.  I don't need these data as it is for testing.  Most of the documentation says to use

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'
```

However, localhost:9200 isn't reachable (it was previously), presumably because elasticsearch cannot be properly started so it is a bit of chicken and egg.

Is there a way for me to clear away all elasticsearch data manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some remaining indices that are incompatible with your newest ES version, most certainly you were on ES 1.x before.

You can simply delete anything under the `$ES_HOME/data/*` folder. Since you installed ES via brew, `ES_HOME` is usually located at `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch`

Comment: Thanks, I installed elasticsearch on my Mac via homebrew, then did a homebrew upgrade.  The ES_HOME variable is undefined.  But I do have a couple of directories under /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch.  There is a 5.3.1 folder, and a 5.5.0 folder.  However, neither of them have the data folder.  The index it is complaining about seems to be from my experimentation with document search with the mapper attachment plugin on 5.3.1.

Comment: I went and look up the documentation for elasticsearch directories at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/setup-dir-layout.html.  However, the directory isn't quite the same as the default that I have on my machine with the hombrew install.  I found the offending indices  files under, /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices () $.  If I remove the offending indices (that were created using the mapper attachment plugin), then I can start elasticsearch 5.5.0.  But I have decided to brew switch to 5.3.1 installed on my machine to match Amazon elasticsearch.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  After working out this issue, I posted a follow up question on whether I can lock down on an elasticsearch version with homebrew, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225432/how-can-i-install-elasticsearch-5-3-1-with-homebrew.  Please let me know if you know anything.

Comment: On later versions the data dir is defined in the elasticsearch config, which by default from a homebrew install is located at `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`. In the yml file is a `path.data` setting which lists a directory under which all data is stored. By default this is `/usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/`.